# Run bash command from awk system only once

Tags: shell-script, awk

I am using tail -F to monitor a severe weather alert server log file and awk to filter and execute a command if the conditions for an alert are met. I need to execute the bash command(an ssh command sent to a Pi to trigger an alert LED) in system only once, not one time for every match. Everything is working except the system command is running once for every line matched. Here is what I have so far:

```bsh
tail -F /home/user/test.txt | stdbuf -oL awk '/ZZZ029/{getline; if (/SV.W/) print system("command")}'
```

Current output(number of lines could vary):

```bsh
/O.NEW.KBMX.SV.W.0028.190314T2350Z-190315T0030Z/
/O.CON.KFFC.SV.W.0021.000000T0000Z-190315T0015Z/
/O.NEW.KBMX.SV.W.0028.190314T2350Z-190315T0030Z/
/O.CON.KFFC.SV.W.0021.000000T0000Z-190315T0015Z/
/O.NEW.KBMX.SV.W.0028.190314T2350Z-190315T0030Z/
/O.CON.KFFC.SV.W.0021.000000T0000Z-190315T0015Z/
```

Expected output:

```bsh
/O.NEW.KBMX.SV.W.0028.190314T2350Z-190315T0030Z/
```

I need just one line of output so the system command will run only once. Or just a way to run the command once regardless of number of lines of output.

Comment: after you calll `system("command")` you want the whole pipeline to stop, or you want the pipeline to continue but for awk to never call `system` again?

Comment: Note that `system()` runs `sh` to interpret the `command` not `bash`. If you want to start `bash` to interpret bash specific code, you'll need to construct `sh` code that runs `bash -c bash-specific-code-here` where that bash-specific code will have to be quoted as per sh rules.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I want the tail -F to continue watching the file but to run the system() command only once for each time matches are found, regardless of how many matches there are.

Comment: I'm having trouble putting together these two phrases: "run the system() command once" -- and --  "each time matches are found, regardless of how many matches there are".  Do you want the command run for the *first* match, and that first match only?

Comment: Yes, for the first match only.

Comment: KIndly post input  and expected o/p

Comment: @PraveenKumarBS I edited the post to include these details.

Answer (score 0):

```
From current output what you provided from my understanding you want to remove duplicates

pipeline_previous_command|awk '{if(!seen[$1]++)print $1}'

/O.NEW.KBMX.SV.W.0028.190314T2350Z-190315T0030Z/
/O.CON.KFFC.SV.W.0021.000000T0000Z-190315T0015Z/
```

Suppose if you want ouput as output which mentioned above

```
raveen:~$ pipeline_previous_command |  awk '/W.0028/{if(!seen[$1]++)print $1}'

/O.NEW.KBMX.SV.W.0028.190314T2350Z-190315T0030Z/
```

Comment: Yes, remove duplicates of SV.W match. I'm not understanding how to work this into my current script, however. Does it go after the `getline; if (/SV.W/)` command?

Comment: tail -F /home/user/test.txt | stdbuf -oL awk '/ZZZ029/{getline; if (/SV.W/) print system("command")}'|awk '{if(!seen[$1]++)print $1}'                              use this command